# Diffie-Hellman algorithm between java and Node.js

Tags: java, node.js, crypt, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to simulate java Diffie Hellman codes in Node.JS
in java code I have 'key' and 'prime'
but I'm don't know how to use this values in Node.js code

Java :

```
private static byte[] getSharedSecretKey() {
try {
        String key = "OoJcHg4+2ady0ULZJGFWK0giozYA9Je0Aacu1q9ElbU=";
        String prime = "qYsHeFZ0HlCU+Bnk3zmmtQr+ZkIkux8M/EQVSvzXFZs=";
        KeyPair generateKeyPair;
        DHParameterSpec dHParameterSpec = new DHParameterSpec(new BigInteger(1, Base64.decode(prime,2)), BigInteger.valueOf(2));
        KeyPairGenerator instance = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DiffieHellman");
        instance.initialize(dHParameterSpec);
        generateKeyPair = instance.generateKeyPair();
        KeyAgreement keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DiffieHellman");
        PrivateKey privateKey = generateKeyPair.getPrivate();

        keyAgreement.init(privateKey);

        String encodeToString3 = Base64.encodeToString(((DHPublicKey) generateKeyPair.getPublic()).getY().toByteArray(), 2);
        Log.i("pooya2",encodeToString3);
        

        PublicKey generatePublic = KeyFactory.getInstance("DiffieHellman").generatePublic(new DHPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(1, Base64.decode(key,2)), new BigInteger(1, Base64.decode(prime,2)), BigInteger.valueOf(2)));
        keyAgreement.doPhase(generatePublic, true);
        byte[] bArr = keyAgreement.generateSecret();
        return bArr;
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Node.js :

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

var p ="76686514709098868078547561269724999506546756740829312045036485484543791797659";
var key ="26464471107213172395531456221994106144264598183422226468709095454165464028597";
var g= 2;

let diffiehellmangrp1 = crypto.createDiffieHellman(Buffer.from(p,).toString("hex"),"hex",2);
let diffiehellmangrp2 = crypto.createDiffieHellman(Buffer.from(p,).toString("hex"),"hex",2);
// Generating keys
let alicePublicKey = diffiehellmangrp1.generateKeys();
let bobPublicKey = diffiehellmangrp2.generateKeys();
console.log("alicePublicKey", new Buffer(alicePublicKey).toString('base64'));
console.log("bobPublicKey", new Buffer(bobPublicKey).toString('base64'));

// Computing secret
const diffiehellmangrp1sc = diffiehellmangrp1 .computeSecret(Buffer.from(key,).toString("hex"), 'hex', 'base64');
console.log("aliceKey", diffiehellmangrp1sc);

const diffiehellmangrp2sc = diffiehellmangrp2 .computeSecret(Buffer.from(key,).toString("hex"), 'hex', 'base64');
console.log("bobKey", diffiehellmangrp2sc);
```

Are 'key' and 'prime' used correctly in their places?
thats give me another result and not like java

Comment: `Mg==` is not the base64 of the number 2 (which is the generator you used in Java); it is the base64 of the number 50, which is the ASCII-and-later code of the _character_ `2`. For the number 2 use `Ag==`. With that change it looks like it works to me; if you think there is another problem you should state clearly (in your Q) what you expect and how this differs.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks i'm edited the code, please check it, that's give me another result and not like java, Are 'key' and 'prime' used correctly in their places?

Comment: Define 'like'. Both your Java and nodejs code use ephemeral keypairs for local (and a static public key for remote), so every time you run _either_ of them you get a different local key and resulting secret. Two runs of Java are different; two runs of nodejs are different; a run of Java and a run of nodejs are different. But your modified nodejs code no longer uses the same values for p and (other)key as the Java, so they won't interoperate with the same peer. You are now using the characters of the decimal string, which makes no sense, and won't even be the same size, and likely not prime.